# Moment.js to display the year month day and hours

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am using the moment.js to display the Time in a specific formation -

```
var a = moment(new Date());
      var b = moment(data.passwordLastSet);

      var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
      b.add(years, 'years');

      var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
      b.add(months, 'months');

      var days = a.diff(b, 'days');

      var hour = a.diff(b, 'hours')
      b.add(hour, 'months');
      this.passwordAgeYear = years;
      this.passwordAge = years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days ' + hour + ' hours'
```

The above code display the date and time in below format

**0 years 0 months 1 days 37 hours**

I have a requirement to display something like this

**0 years 0 months 1 days 13 hours**

I have tried to use the fromNow and from

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

But couldn't get the output. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code have some an error, it should be like this,

```
var a = moment(new Date());
var b = moment(data.passwordLastSet);
var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');
var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');
var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
b.add(days, 'days');
var hour = a.diff(b, 'hours');
this.passwordAgeYear = years;
this.passwordAge = years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days ' + hour + ' hours';
```

In short, you forgot to add the days to `b`, that is why you have `days * 24 + hours` in hours.